# How do I write helper functions to read/write my NSDictionary to my Property List?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am working on an  iPhone app that allows certain data to be read from and saved to a property list, but my read function isn't working properly. If I am correct in my thinking, I should simply be able to reverse the procedure I took for reading to write the write helper function. I was able to use [NSArray* dic valueForKey] successfully but my NSLog statements are printing nothing. The program isn't crashing, but it isn't displaying logged values in the output window either. I am not sure I found my filePath correctly, created the dictionary or the array. I am aware I have to call my init function in the main viewcontroller as well but am having difficulty doing so.

My function declarations in the data header are as follows:

```
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableArray *listOfGroups;

    + (AllData*) myGroupList;

    -(NSString*) plistFilePath;

    -(NSMutableArray*) withNSMutableArrayInit: (NSMutableArray*) arr;
```

My functions in the data implementation are as follows:

```
    -(NSString *) plistFilePath
    {
        //---1.Find the property list filePath
        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Group.plist"];
        return documentsDir;


        //---2. Create a dictionary and initialize with contents of file.---
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:documentsDir];


        //---3. Create an array of type arrayWithArray:[dictionary allValues].---
        NSArray* array= [NSArray arrayWithArray:dictionary];
        return [self plistFilePath];
    }

    - (NSMutableArray*) WithNSMutableArrayInit: (NSMutableArray*) arr
    {
    [self plistFilePath];

    for (NSDictionary *dic in arr)
    {
        NSString *groupName = [dic valueForKey:@"groupName"];
        NSLog(groupName);
        NSString *createDate = [dic valueForKey:@"createDate"];
        NSString *totalAmount = [dic valueForKey:@"totalAmount"];
        NSString *totalPeople = [dic valueForKey:@"totalPeople"];
        NSArray* participantList = [dic valueForKey:@"ParticipantList"];

        for (NSDictionary *dic in arr)
        {
            NSString *participantName = [dic valueForKey:@"participantName"];
            NSLog(participantName);
            NSString *relatedParticipantList = [dic valueForKey:@"relatedParticipantList"];
            NSString *relatedAmountList = [dic valueForKey:@"relatedAmountList"];
        }

        NSArray* recordList = [dic valueForKey:@"recordList"];
        for (NSDictionary *dic in arr)
        {
            NSString *recordCategory = [dic valueForKey:@"recordCategory"];
            NSLog(recordCategory);
            NSString *recordDateTime = [dic valueForKey:@"recordDateTime"];
            NSString *recordAmount = [dic valueForKey:@"recordAmount"];
        }

    }

return [self listOfGroups];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plistFilePath method is returning early with the user documents path, rather than the file path. Did you mean to do that? It looks like a bug.

Not to mention you'll have an infinite loop if you fixed that bug, by calling [self plistFilePath] at the final (currently unreachable) return statement.

Comment: I didn't mean to do that, though I would greatly appreciate it if you could assist me. How would I go about fixing that infinite loop and making the final return statement reachable?

Comment: I'd like to help but truthfully, you're question shows a great misunderstanding of objective c like H2CO3 said. There are way more bugs. Look up iphone intro courses on iTunes U.

Comment: I have no qualms in admitting that I have significantly more difficulty with this language in particular than I have any others I've worked with. I've seen the intro courses, I'm already in the process of working through them on top of everything in my iOS course.

Comment: Good luck, keep learning. You will succeed if you keep trying.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the input, even if it was not what I hoped for.

Comment: If you have any interest in advancing, then what I said is the best answer you will get, even if it's not the one you want. I have been working in Objective C for many years, so I know what I am talking about.

Comment: Trust me, I've been at it long enough to have confirmed my interest in advancing. If I wanted to quit, I'd have done so years ago.